# Proof about logic interpretations and formulas

Tags: proof-verification, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Is this solution for the exercise correct?

> Although, by (VI), $(∀x)A(x )$
>    is true whenever A( x
>   )
>   is true, find
>   an interpretation for which $A(x)\to\forall xA(x)$ is not true.

By Lemma (seen in class), $\vDash\phi$ iff $\vDash CL(\phi)$ which is the closure of $\phi$, we have $A(x)$ is closed and by (VI),  $A(x)$ is true iff $\forall xA(x)$ is true, in particular if $A(x)$ is true, then $\forall xA(x)$ is true as well under any interpretation.

Therefore it's impossible to find an interpretation for which $A(x)\to\forall xA(x)$ is not true.

**(VI)** $\vDash_M\phi \iff\vDash_M\forall x_i\phi,$ where by definition $\phi$ is closed.

Comment: "P is true whenever Q is true" is not an if and only if statement.

Comment: Why do "we have $A(x)$ is closed"? It doesn't look closed to me, because it has a free variable $x$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Closed if it's true under an interpretation M, but I don't know if I can make that assumption.

Comment: It seems you're using "closed" to mean something other than "having no free variables", but I have no idea what that other meaning might be.

Comment: @AndreasBlass no. Well forget about the proof I did above (I think it's very wrong), The new idea is to close $A(x)$ to get this $\forall xA(x)\to\forall xA(x)$ and then this $\forall xA(x)\to\forall yA(y)$ and then to try to find an interpretation I such that it makes F, i.e. $[A(x)\to\forall yA(y)]$=F. What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand what your most recent comment means, but it seems that you are surrounding the original question with a lot of unnecessary complications. I'd suggest proceeding very directly, by working out what it means for an interpretation to make $A(x)\to\forall x\,A(x)$ false. Start by using the truth table for implication to see that your interpretation will need to make $A(x)$ true and make $\forall x\,A(x)$ false. Then continue analyzing those requirements, using the rest of the definition of what it means for an interpretation to make formulas true or false.

Comment: ok but how will I assign a value (T or F) to $A(x)$ if it has free variables?, I need to close it.

Comment: $(x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$ is not *true* in $\mathbb N$ because its closure: $\forall x ((x=0) \to \forall x (x=0))$ is not true in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your statement (IV) says, is that if $\phi$ is closed, then we have $\vDash\phi \iff\vDash\forall x\phi$

Essentially, what your task wants to emphasize is that the condition that $\phi$ needs to be closed is really necessary, so they want you to realize that $\vDash\phi \iff\vDash\forall x\phi$ does not hold if we don't require $\phi$ to be closed. Your task already gives you a hint as of which direction of this $\iff$ does not hold. Additionally it hints at the fact that a formula of the form $\phi=A(x)$ is already enough to find a counterexample.

So now to the counterexample: You know that $\vDash\phi \iff\vDash\forall x\phi$ holds for all closed $\phi$. As you want to find a counterexample, you know this counterexample can't be closed, and indeed your $\phi=A(x)$ is not closed, as $x$ is free.

For the interpretation you can do pretty much do anything you want, let me just give you one example for an interpretation $I$ over the domain $\mathbb{N}$:

$I(x)=5$

$I(A)=\{n:n<7\}$

So basically what this task shows, is that just because a statement is true for some interpretation, it does not necessarily mean the statement is true for all interpretations.

Comment: I don't understand the way you gave the interpretations, it's supposed to write $A(x)=... $, and then $I(A)=F $ or $I(A)=V $

Comment: An interpretation is just a function. It maps all free variables ($x$ for us) to some element in the domain ($\mathbb{N}$) and all predicates ($A$) to a subset of the domain. $A(x)$ is true iff $I(x) \in I(A)$ or in other words, $I(A)$ specifies all domain elements for which $A$ returns true. So with our interpretation, $A(x)$ is true. However,  $\forall x A(x)$ is not true, because not all numbers are smaller than 7. (Note that this is not the free $x$ we interpreted. It has nothing to do with that $x$, it's a different $x$ in the scope of the $\forall$).

Comment: By the way I imagine there are different ways to write down interpretations, and to be honest I'm only familiar with the one I was taught. So feel free to use the notation you learned.

Comment: What does A(x) mean in our interpretation? $A(x)=\{n:n<7\}$?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is basically the predicate $numberIsSmallerThanSeven$, i.e. $A(x) \iff x<7$

Comment: And why is true ? It's true for some numbers, but then this would be related to something like this $\exists x A(x)\to\forall x A(x)$ and we have just this $A(x)\to\forall x A(x)$.

Comment: Exactly, with our interpretation of $A$, $A(x)$ is true for some $x$, but not all. That means $\forall x A(x)$ is false. But whether $A(x)$ is true only depends on our interpretation of $x$, so we can chose an $x$ for which $x$ is true (i.e. a witness for $\exists x A(x)$). So with our interpretation of $x$ and $A$, we have that $A(x)$ is true, but $\forall x A(x)$ is not. Therefore we don't have $A(x) \to \forall x A(x)$ with our interpretation $I$, which is exactly what the task asked us.

Comment: That's more clear:) thank you.